# Unity rotation using c# function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am making a PC building game and I have created a case and a motherboard. I wanted the motherboard to snap with the case whenever the distance between them is < 10.

But instead of the motherboard snapping horizontally to the case, it snapped vertically and went through the case. I have tried adjusting the rotation of the motherboard using c# script so that whenever it snaps, it has a fixed rotation but still, it didn't work. Both case and motherboard have rigid body and mesh collider.[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUqAF.png)

And this the snapping script attached to the case(the Ram stands for motherboard):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RamSnap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Ram;
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0.053f,3.3f,0.3f);
    public Quaternion offset2 = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
    public float distance = 10.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float dist1 = Vector3.Distance(Ram.transform.position, transform.position);
        if (dist1 < distance)
        {
            Ram.transform.position = transform.position + offset;
            Ram.transform.rotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(offset2);
            Ram.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
            Debug.Log("Snapped");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Please help fix the problem so that the motherboard can be in the correct orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Your snapping script is flawed because it sets the motherboard's rotation equal to the rotation of the case multiplied by the offset rotation's inverse. As a result, the motherboard will rotate in lockstep with the case's movement before rotating in reverse to match the offset rotation. The motherboard is breaking vertically and passing through the casing because of this.

You must immediately set the motherboard's rotation to the offset rotation in order to resolve this. A modified version of your script is provided below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RamSnap : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject Ram;
  public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0.053f,3.3f,0.3f);
  public Quaternion offset2 = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
  public float distance = 10.0f;
  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    float dist1 = Vector3.Distance(Ram.transform.position, transform.position);
    if (dist1 < distance)
    {
      Ram.transform.position = transform.position + offset;
      Ram.transform.rotation = offset2;
      Ram.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
      Debug.Log("Snapped");
    }
     
  }

}
```

This script will now snap the motherboard to the case in the correct orientation.

Comment: Hmm... It didn't work, I can't change the rotation.